# Get length of data from inputstream opened by content-resolver

Tags: inputstream, httpurlconnection, android-contentresolver

I am doing video (and also photo) uploading to the server by using HttpURLConnection.

I have an Uri of a video. I open an InputStream this way:

```
    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

As video file is pretty big, I can't buffer data while writing it into the outputStream. So I need to use setFixedLengthStreamingMode(contentLength) method of HttpURLConnection. But it requires "contentLength".
The question is, how to get the length of the video?

Please don't suggest getting filepath. On some devices it works, but it often fails (especially on Android 6). They say Uri doesn't necessarily represent a file.

I also stumbled onto situations when after opening device gallery (with Intent) I receive an Uri of a picture, but I fail trying to get filepath from it. So I believe it's not a good way to get filepath from Uri?

Comment: you need not neither to buffer the video entirely nor to know its length in advance to upload it. Have you considered this possibility?

Comment: @nandsito, I'm sorry, could you be more clear, please? I didn't get what you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```java
void uploadVideo() {

    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

    // Your connection.
    HttpURLConnection connection;

    // Do connection setup, setDoOutput etc.

    // Be sure that the server is able to handle
    // chunked transfer encoding.
    connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

    OutputStream connectionOs = connection.getOutputStream();

    // Read and write a 4 KiB chunk a time.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        connectionOs.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    // Close streams, do connection etc.
}
```

**UPDATE**: added `setChunkedStreamingMode`

Comment: This is what I used to do and as it turned out HttpURLConnection buffers all data before sending it. So I get OOM error at some point.